# pop up se cierra al enviar información de formulario

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, popup

lo que pasa es que tengo un formulario incrustado en un pop up pero al enviar la información se cierra el pop up y no puedo ver el mensaje de confirmación

```
<section class="popup">
                <div id="myModal" class="modal" style="overflow-y: auto;" >
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <span class="close">&times;</span>
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <p>Evita sanciones por el incumplimiento de la ley. Tu tranquilidad empieza con una tributación sana.</p>
                                <img src="assets/images/flechablanca.png" alt="Diagnostico">
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-sm-6">
                                <h2>Solicita hoy tu diagnóstico <strong>gratis</strong></h2>
                                <form action="/action_page.php">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailsqyhh">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwdsjkn">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <input type="aa" class="form-control" id="pwdfff">
                                    </div>
                                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </section>

<script>
            // Get the modal
            var modal = document.getElementById('myModal');
            // Get the button that opens the modal
            var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");
            var btn2 = document.getElementById("myBtn2");
            var btn3 = document.getElementById("myBtn3");
            // Get the <span> element that closes the modal
            var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
            // When the user clicks on the button, open the modal 
            btn.onclick = function() {
                modal.style.display = "block";
            }
            btn2.onclick = function() {
                modal.style.display = "block";
            }
            btn3.onclick = function() {
                modal.style.display = "block";
            }
            // When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
            span.onclick = function() {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
            // When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
            window.onclick = function(event) {
                if (event.target == modal) {
                    modal.style.display = "none";
                }
            }
        </script>
```

estoy usando wordpress entonces el formulario lo cambio por el shortcode que me da el plugin contac form 7

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

La linea que oculta el modal es la que dice modal.style.display = "none", podrías hacer que se cierre a los 3 segundos reemplazándola por algo como esto:

```
window.setTimeout(function(){ modal.style.display = "none"; }, 3000);
```

Espero te sirva.
¡Suerte!

Comment: voy a probar aver

Comment: lo probe y ahora no se acciona el pop up

Comment: ¿Se ve algún error en la consola del navegador?

Comment: ya se dispara el pop pup no me fije que tenia mal el parentesis, pero aun asi se sigue cerrando el pop up y no me muestra el mensaje de confirmacion, pero cuando vuelvo a abrir el pop up se muestra el mensaje

Comment: la consola no me muestra errores

Comment: Que error te muestra?

Answer (score 0):

El popup se cierra porque tienes un botón tipo **submit** y este tipo de botones envia el formulario haciendo refrescar la página; puedes hacer dos cosas, la primera cambiando el tipo por **button** ó colocando en el evento submit del formulario **event.preventDefault()** para prevenir su comportamiento por defecto:

```
$("#myModal form").submit(function(event){
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

Cualquiera que fuese los dos casos deberías de implementar un **ajax** posteriormente para enviar los datos y asi poder controlar cuando tu quieras cuando se cierra la modal ejemplo:

Cambiando el tipo a **button**:

**HTML**

```
<section class="popup">
  <div id="myModal" class="modal" style="overflow-y: auto;" >
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <p>Evita sanciones por el incumplimiento de la ley. Tu tranquilidad empieza con una tributación sana.</p>
          <img src="assets/images/flechablanca.png" alt="Diagnostico">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h2>Solicita hoy tu diagnóstico <strong>gratis</strong></h2>
          <form action="/action_page.php">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailsqyhh">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwdsjkn">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="aa" class="form-control" id="pwdfff">
            </div>
            <button id="enviar" type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Como veras cambie el tipo del botón a **button** y le coloque un **id** para asignarle un evento **click** para luego llamar a un **ajax**:

**JS**

```
$("#enviar").on("click", function(){

  //Obtenemos los datos del formulario
  let correo = $("#emailsqyhh").val();
  let clave = $("#pwdsjkn").val();

  var formAction = $('#myModal').find("form").attr('action');
  $.ajax({
      url: formAction,
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {correo: correo, clave: clave},
      error: function(objeto, quepaso, otroobj){
      },
      success: function(data){
        //Aquí obtienes la respuesta
        //y puedes cerrar el popup
      }
  });

});
```

Con el evento **submit** del formulario:

**HTML**

```
<section class="popup">
  <div id="myModal" class="modal" style="overflow-y: auto;" >
    <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <p>Evita sanciones por el incumplimiento de la ley. Tu tranquilidad empieza con una tributación sana.</p>
          <img src="assets/images/flechablanca.png" alt="Diagnostico">
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-6">
          <h2>Solicita hoy tu diagnóstico <strong>gratis</strong></h2>
          <form action="/action_page.php">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="emailsqyhh">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwdsjkn">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="aa" class="form-control" id="pwdfff">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**JS**

```
$("#myModal form").submit(function(event){

  event.preventDefault();

  //Obtenemos los datos del formulario
  let correo = $("#emailsqyhh").val();
  let clave = $("#pwdsjkn").val();

  var formAction = $('#myModal').find("form").attr('action');
  $.ajax({
    url: formAction,
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: {correo: correo, clave: clave},
    error: function(objeto, quepaso, otroobj){
    },
    success: function(data){
      //Aquí obtienes la respuesta
      //y puedes cerrar el popup
    }
  });

});
```

Comment: me sale error 404 con la url :(

Comment: y el otro formulario que tengo ya no funciona, es que tengo dos formularios uno arriba y el otro abajo y el del popup es el mismo del de abajo

Comment: Claro la url  tienes que colocar la que en verdad va, en url del ajax coloca entre comillas la url donde deberia de ir, y a los formularios colocales un id para diferenciarlos y donde coloque $("form") colocas $("#eliddelform")

Comment: los formularios son de wordpress no he podido colocarles id

Comment: en la modal cuantos formularios tienes? dentro de la modal ojo, solo uno?

Comment: dentro del modal solo hay uno, con el shortcode que me da wordpress lo coloque dentro del modal con el echo do_shortcode

Comment: Ok entonces puedes modificar esto $("form") y usar $('#myModal').find("form") y $('#myModal form') porque si solo usamos $("form") es muy generico y tratara de buscar todos los formularios, hay que enviar el que es, pruebalo y me avisas ya modifique mi respuesta

Comment: ya me funcionan, pero el form de del popup no se activa

Comment: y no me muestra error por consola

Answer (score 0):

En mi opinión el código está bien, pero te falta un par de líneas:

En tu código pones:

```
// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
        window.onclick = function(event) {
            if (event.target == modal) {
                modal.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
```

Y yo añadiría:

```
$('#myModal').click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

O bien:

```
$('.popup').click(function(event){
   event.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: el popup se sigue cerrando cuando envio el formulario